# Method overloading decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to write a decorator that provides method overloading functionality to python, similar to the one mentioned in [PEP 3124](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3124/).

The decorator I wrote works great for regular functions, but I can't get it to work for methods in a class.

Here is the decorator:

```
class Overload(object):
    def __init__(self, default):
        self.default_function = default
        self.type_map = {}
        self.pos = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print self
        try:
            if self.pos is None:
                pos = kwargs.get("pos", 0)
            else:
                pos = self.pos
            print args, kwargs
            return self.type_map[type(args[pos])](*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            return self.default_function(*args, **kwargs)
        except IndexError:
            return self.default_function(*args, **kwargs)

    def overload(self, *d_type):
        def wrapper(f):
            for dt in d_type:
                self.type_map[dt] = f
            return self
        return wrapper
```

When I attempt to implement it like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_instance_var = 1

    @Overload
    def print_first_item(self, x):
        return x[0], self.some_instance_var

    @print_first_item.overload(str)
    def print_first_item(self, x):
        return x.split()[0], self.some_instance_var
```

I get a `TypeError` when I run it:

```
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.print_first_item(1) 
<__main__.Overload object at 0x2> (1,) {} 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
  File "overload.py", line 17, in __call__
    return self.default_function(*args, **kwargs) 
  TypeError: print_first_item() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>>>
```

My question is: *How can I access the instance of `MyClass` (i.e. `self`) from within the decorated method?*

Comment: Have you looked at the reference implementation in PEAK.Rules, or any of the dozen other reference implementations attached to pje's earlier PEPs and list posts? If you're trying to actually use this, rather than trying to explore Python, it probably makes more sense to use his work (which at least a few other people have used and tested) than to repeat it.

Comment: @abarnert: I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for the heads up. That being said, I'm really just wondering why my implementation isn't working as expected and how I could fix it. I am, as you say "exploring Python".

Comment: First, do you know about @functools.wraps, etc.? They'll make your life a lot easier, but that's not going to help you here. Anyway, the first part of the problem here is that your default_function is being replaced it with a function-like class that's not a method (Overload.__call__ takes a self, but that's the Overload instance, not the MyClass). But obviously you can't just do __call__(self, realself, *args, **kwargs) and expect that to work. I don't have time to get into detail tonight; hopefully someone else can help before I get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, your `Overload` class needs a `__get__` method:

```
def __get__(self, obj, cls):
    # Called on access of MyClass.print_first_item.
    # We return a wrapper which calls our 
    print "get", self, obj, cls
    if obj is None:
        # a function would do some checks here, but we leave that.
        return self
    else:
        return lambda *a, **k: self(obj, *a, **k)
```

Why?

Well, you use your `Overload` object as a kind of function replacement. You want it, like a function, to represent itself in a method context with different signature.

Short explanation how method access works:

```
object.meth(1, 2)
```

gets translated to

```
object.__dict__['meth'].__get__(object, type(object))(1, 2)
```

A function's `__get__()` returns a method object which wraps the function by prepending the object to the parameter list (where it results in `self`):

```
realmethod = object.__dict__['meth'].__get__(object, type(object))
realmethod(1, 2)
```

where `realmethod` is a method object which knows the function to be called and the `self` to be given to it and calls the "real" function appropriately by transforming the call into

```
meth(object, 1, 2)
```

.

This behaviour we imitate in this new `__get__` method.

Comment: Awesome. Using your advice, I got it to work. +1 for the detailed explanation of how lookups work.

Answer (score 1):

as abarnert says as you are using a class as your decorator 'self' is an instance of Overload rather than MyClass as you hope/expect.

I couldn't find a simple solution. The best thing I could come up with is not using a class as a decorator and instead use a function but with a second argument with a default of a dictionary. Since this is an mutable type it will be the same dictionary every time the function is called. I use this to store my 'class variables'. The rests folows a similar pattern to your solution.

Example:

```
import inspect

def overload(funcOrType, map={}, type=None):
    if not inspect.isclass(funcOrType):
        # We have a function so we are dealing with "@overload"
        if(type):
            map[type] = funcOrType
        else:
            map['default_function'] = funcOrType
    else:
        def overloadWithType(func):
            return overload(func, map, funcOrType)
        return  overloadWithType

    def doOverload(*args, **kwargs):
        for type in [t for t in map.keys() if t != 'default_function'] :
            if isinstance(args[1], type): # Note args[0] is 'self' i.e. MyClass instance.
                return map[type](*args, **kwargs)
        return map['default_function'](*args, **kwargs)

    return doOverload
```

Then:

```
from overload import *

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_instance_var = 1

    @overload
    def print_first_item(self, x):
        return x[0], self.some_instance_var

    @overload(str)
    def print_first_item(self, x):
        return x.split()[0], self.some_instance_var


m = MyClass()
print (m.print_first_item(['a','b','c']))
print (m.print_first_item("One Two Three"))
```

Yeilds:

```
('a', 1)
('One', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here is the working implementation, thanks to the detailed explanation by glglgl:

```
argtype_tuple = lambda args: tuple(type(a) for a in args)

class Overload(object):    
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.default = func
        self.map = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        key_tuple = argtype_tuple(args)
        c_inst = kwargs.pop("c_inst", None)
        if c_inst:
            args = (c_inst,) + args
        try:
            return self.map[key_tuple](*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            return self.default(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj:
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: self(c_inst=obj, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self

    def overload(self, *types):
        def wrapper(f):
            for type_seq in types:
                if type(type_seq) == tuple:
                    type_seq = tuple(type_seq)
                else:
                    type_seq = (type_seq,)
                self.map[type_seq] = f
            return self
        return wrapper

#Some tests/usage examples
class A(object):
    @Overload
    def print_first(self, x):
        return x[0]

    @print_first.overload(str)
    def p_first(self, x):
        return x.split()[0]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "class A Instance"

a = A()
assert a.print_first([1,2,3]) == 1
assert a.print_first("one two three") == "one"

@Overload
def flatten(seq):
    return [seq]

@flatten.overload(list, tuple)
def flat(seq):
    return sum((flatten(item) for item in seq), [])

assert flatten([1,2,[3,4]]) == [1,2,3,4]
assert flat([1,2,[3,4]]) == [1,2,3,4]
```