# How to hint a custom overload decorator correctly?

Tags: python, overloading, decorator, python-decorators

is there anyone knows how to overload hint like the default `overload.decorator` do?

I have a custom working overload decorator, but **cannot hint correctly**.

* the way to custom overload decorator for example

- [Method overloading decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371309/method-overloading-decorator)

The reason behind doing this is because of :

- 1: Default `overload.decorator` is only for decoration
- 2: Alternative ways like `multipledispatch.dispatch` are not from standard library

---

For example, in vscode, the default @overload will hint like below

```
from typing import overload


class Foo :

    @overload
    def bar( self , value : int ) -> int : ...

    @overload
    def bar( self , value : str ) -> str : ...
```

[image]

---

The custom overload decorator, however, will only display the last loaded method.

```
def custom_overload( * types ) : 

    # logic to resolve callable
    ...

class Foo :

    @custom_overload( int )
    def bar( self , value : int ) -> int : ...
    
    @custom_overload( str )
    def bar( self , value : str ) -> str : ...
```

[image]

---

How can I hint the decorated callable like the default `overload.decorator` do.

Is it related to this?

[How to document Python functions with overload/dispatch decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347628/how-to-document-python-functions-with-overload-dispatch-decorators)

Thank you for your advises.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not alternative way, this will be the only one solution for python at this moment. Its ugly but, below is what I will do.

```
# default overload 
from typing import overload as hint

# custom overload
def overload( * types ) : 

    # logic to resolve callable
    ...

class Foo :

    @hint
    def bar( self , value : int ) -> int : ...

    @hint
     def bar( self , value : str ) -> str : ...

    @overload( int )
    def bar( self , value : int ) -> int : ...
    
    @overload( str )
    def bar( self , value : str ) -> str : ...
```